# How can I create a link to an interface in Doxygen for a PHP project?

Tags: php, interface, documentation, doxygen, phpdoc

Given the code

```
namespace DigitalPublications\MidasWPX;

use DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\StyleInterface;
use DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\PathsManagerInterface;

/**
 *
 * @author Chris Athanasiadis <chris.k.athanasiadis@gmail.com>
 *        
 */
final class Style extends Base implements StyleInterface {

    /**
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     *
     * $config parameters:
     * <br>
     * - pathsManager {@link PathsManagerInterface PathsManagerInterface}
     */
    protected function construct(array $config = array()) {
        /**
         *
         * @internal
         * @var \DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\PathsManagerInterface $pathsManager
         */
        $pathsManager = $this->options->get('pathsManager', $config);
    }
}
```

The part

```
* - pathsManager {@link PathsManagerInterface PathsManagerInterface}
```

Should have created a link to the `PathsManagerInterface` interface, but instead [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) throws an error `warning: unable to resolve link to 'PathsManagerInterface' for \link command`.

If I use a class and not an interface, it works as expected.

**UPDATE**

After @albert comment, I include some other info as well:

Interface code

```
namespace DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces;

/**
 * Manager for paths
 *  
 * @author Chris Athanasiadis <chris.k.athanasiadis@gmail.com>
 *        
 */
interface PathsManagerInterface extends ManagerInterface {

}
```

Operating system is macOS High Sierra

Doxygen version is 1.8.17

Settings that are changed from default values are:

- OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C
- ABBREVIATE_BRIEF
- STRIP_FROM_PATH
- HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES
- RECURSIVE

**UPDATE 2**

Link to class that works.

Class

```
namespace DigitalPublications\MidasWPX;

use DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Manager\Manager;
use DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\PathsManagerInterface;

/**
 *
 * @author Chris Athanasiadis <chris.k.athanasiadis@gmail.com>
 *        
 */
final class PathsManager extends Manager implements PathsManagerInterface {

    /**
     *
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function initManager(array $managerConfig = array()) {
    }
}
```

Comment changed to

```
* - pathsManager {@link PathsManager PathsManager}
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which settings in your doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) are different from the default values? Please add this information in the question (and also see to it that with this information the example throws the warning). Please also add the working class example.

Comment: I tried: `* - pathsManager {@link DigitalPublications::MidasWPX::Interfaces::PathsManagerInterface PathsManagerInterface}` and got the link (pointing to the right place) and no warning. With `* - pathsManager {@link DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\PathsManagerInterface PathsManagerInterface}` I got a link (pointing to the wrong place as ar as I can see)as well but also a warning about a non resolvable link. BTW how does the working class version look like?

Comment: @albert I'll add to the original question, the working code

Comment: It doesn't seem anything to work. For now I go with this syntax `DigitalPublications::MidasWPX::Interfaces::PathsManagerInterface`, which is the only way for it to work

Comment: I think this is indeed the only way at the moment, I'm looking into the possibility of `DigitalPublications\MidasWPX\Interfaces\PathsManagerInterface` as I think this is more "PHP like".

Comment: @albert I've tried it as well, but with no luck. Thanks anyway!

Comment: The version with the backslash doesn't work, but I created a proposed pull request: https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/pull/7574